# MS Word how to remove the "-" splitting a word to justify a paragraph?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I want to remove the `"-"` splitting a word to justify a paragraph.
I tried to use the following replace

[image]

But when applying it I get `->` instead

**example**

```
he want to gener-
ate the idea
```

**output**

```
he want to gener->ate the idea
```

This is a word document converted from PDF. disabling hyphenation is not working

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are trying to disable *hyphenation*, which is when Word
breaks a word to fit it into the line.

To disable hyphenation :

- Select the text.
- On the Home tab, Paragraph group, click the small
  button on the bottom-right of the group,
  or right-click the text and select "Paragraph..."
- In the Paragraph dialog box, select the "Line and Page Breaks" tab
- Under Formatting exceptions, select check "Don't hyphenate"
- Click OK.

Comment: well, I'm aware of this but this is a PDF file I converted to word. MS WORD does not detect that it's hyphenation.

Comment: This information should have been included in your answer. Could you post the file online (Dropbox, OneDrive etc)?